# My reducer is triggered twice when I call it once. There something strange when I try to fix it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-reducer

Here is [my code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-66i5zh?file=src%2Fundo_redo%2FuseUndoUtil.js).
The demo site is [here](https://react-66i5zh.stackblitz.io/def).

On the demo web page, I have 2 buttons, 1 is the "go" button, the other one is the "Back" button. Suppose when I click on the "go" button, the present value will be shown in the console in the following format:

```
before:{"a":[12,27],"b":[63,14]}
after:{"a":[75,27],"b":[63,14]}
```

Unfortunately, the actual result as the following:

```
before:{"a":[12,27],"b":[63,14]}
after:{"a":[75,27],"b":[63,14]}
before:{"a":[12,27],"b":[63,14]}
after:{"a":[75,27],"b":[63,14]}
```

When I comment the following lines in the `DEF` componet:

```
setTimeout(()=>{
  setContextValue({undoUtil});
},10)
```

Then, the present value will be shown in the console in the correct format.
However, it does not trigger the screen layout refresh.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: `flag` is not state, saying `flag = true` inside the effect does nothing.

Comment: The `flag` variable will be initialized every time the component renders. If you want to persist its value. Create a state for it.

Comment: I have changed it to a state variable, the problem still exists.

Comment: not according to the code you're showing: if you change your code, what happens changes, which means your question changes, so update your post.

Comment: I have updated it.

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem in the `DEF.js`. Maybe the following code caused the problem.

```
  temp["a"][0] = 75;
  undoUtil.set(temp);
  temp['a'][1]=20;
  undoUtil.set(temp);
```

All of the `undoUtil.set` are using the same variable `temp`, maybe something is overwritten.

Besides that, in the `useUndoUtil.js` the set method may has same problem,

```
    case "set":
        console.log("before:"+JSON.stringify(state.presentValue));
        let temp=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.pastValue));
        temp.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.presentValue)));
        state.pastValue=temp;
        state.presentValue=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(action.value));
        console.log("after:"+JSON.stringify(state.presentValue));
        return state;
        break;
```

After I change the code in `DEF.js` as the below:

```
temp['a'][0]=75;    
undoUtil.set(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(temp)));
temp['a'][1]=20;
undoUtil.set(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(temp)));
```

And the code in `useUndoUtil.js` as the following:

```
case "set":
    let temp=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.pastValue));
    temp.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.presentValue)));
    return {
      pastValue:temp,
      presentValue:JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(action.value))
    }
    break;
```

It seems working as I expected. Thank you, Adam, if none concerns the question,
I won't retry to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually trying to do? It's incredibly unclear. The reason why you're seeing it logged in the console twice is because you have two calls to `undoUtil.set`

```
    setTimeout(() => {
      temp["a"][0] = 75;
      undoUtil.set(temp);
    }, 0);

    setTimeout(
      ()=>{
        temp['a'][1]=20;
        undoUtil.set(temp);
      }
    ,0);
```

Why the setTimeout's? What's going on?

Not an answer, I know, but too long for a comment.

Comment: Thank you for your concern about my question. after several trials, I found that the setTimeout can help to solve the problem.

Comment: @TheKNVB - As a general rule, if you can fix something by using `setTimeout`, you most likely just made it worse.